# athena prepared statement how to pass multiple values in IN cluase

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

i have a prepared statement with IN clause

```
SELECT locationId,
    location,
FROM location_type
where city in (?)
    and userId = ?
```

i tried executing the above query with prepared statement query

```
execute ps using 'NY','CA','12345';
```

but this is being taken as 3 parameters, i also tried the above query in AWS console passing 'NY','CA' in param1 and '12345' in param2 but it doesn't returns any result.

Tried other way of taking both values as JSON array and then converting to string with comma separated values but that also doesn't returns any result

```
SELECT locationId,
    location,
FROM location_type
where city in (array_join(cast(? as array(varchar)), ', '))
    and userId = ?

execute ps using json '["NY","CA"]','12345';
```

couldn't find any examples too for IN clause in athena/presto

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using IN you could use a CTE.

Here is an example of what the basic CTE would look like:

```
with city_list_cte as (
    select *
    from (
            select '["NY","CA"]' as city_list, '12345' as userid --I believe this is where you would substitute ?
        ) as lt
        cross join unnest(
            cast(
                json_parse(city_list) as array < varchar >
            )
        ) as t(city)
)
select *
from city_list_cte
```

Which gives results of:
[image]

It is taking the city list, casting to json and using UNNEST to give you a row for each of those values.

Then you can join that to your other table.  Something like the following but without sample data I can't completely test out:

```
with city_list_cte as (
    select *
    from (
            select '["NY","CA"]' as city_list, '12345' as userid --I believe this is where you would substitute ?
        ) as lt
        cross join unnest(
            cast(
                json_parse(city_list) as array < varchar >
            )
        ) as t(city)
)
SELECT locationId,
    location,
FROM location_type lt
JOIN city_list_cte cl on cl.city = lt.city and cl.userid = lt.userId
```

Where I have the hardcoded values for city_list and userid you would substitute for ? and adjust for your specific needs.

Comment: i solved this with IN clause with A CTE in IN clause, other join is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

In clause doesn't takes comma seperated values as parameter  in Prepared statement, so have to create a CTE with values and break into rows then pass as paramter IN clause

```
SELECT locationId,
    location,
FROM location_type
where city in (select * from
(
WITH t AS (
SELECT ? AS data
)
SELECT value
FROM t
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(split(t.data, ',')) as x(value)))
    and userId = ?


prepared statement can be 

execute ps using json 'NY,CA','12345';
```